# Using Powershell get Values from sql table

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell

we know that we can use sql query window to get values from Database like "`select * from....`". Is there any way to get a value through powershell way. I found the way to database table itself but not to the values..

Ex:

```
Set-location SQLserver:\sql\default\localhost\databases\database\tables
Get-childitem
```

Above command gives me tables in the DB , but how can i get the values from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SQL Server Powershell provider uses SMO to expose the database object hierarchy.  Once you get a SMO child item, you can invoke the corresponding SMO methods on the object.

The SMO Database ExecuteQueryWithResults method can be used to execute a query in the context of a given database.  Get the desired database item and invoke this method to return a DataSet object containing the results.  Then retrieve the data as desired from the DataSet.

Below is an example gleaned from the SMO reference ((https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms205775.aspx) that can be run from the context of the Databases node:

```
$db = Get-Item SomeDatabase
$dt = $db.ExecuteWithResults("SELECT * FROM sys.objects;")
$dt.Tables[0] | Format-Table
```

Comment: What exactly is SomeDatabase? How do I get the database in this example?

Comment: @Alex, "SomeDatabase" is the name of the existing database which you want to run the query against. For example, specify "tempdb" to list the objects in that databse.

Comment: That gives me "Cannot find path 'C:\xxx\xxx...\MyDatabase" because it does not exist. Are we using the same Get-Item?

Comment: @Alex, same command but different context. One way is from SSMS. Right-click on the server in SSMS explorer and select start PowerShell. Then run the Set-Location command. Local host example: `Set-location SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases`

Answer (score 10):

Most concise and straightforward option is [Invoke-SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)

```
$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "mySqlServer" -Database "myDatabase" -Query "SELECT * FROM MyTable"
```

Comment: To test the result is useful Out-GridView 
i.e.
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "mySqlServer" -Database "myDatabase" -Query "SELECT * FROM MyTable" | Out-GridView

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 9):

You can use this

```
$connectionString = “Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=False;”

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$connection.Open()
$query = “SELECT * FROM Tab”

$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: but this is sql server way. for this i need to use sql commands(select * from). My question is how can query a tables in powershell way(using pwershell commands) like get-childitem or get-itemproperty ....

Answer (score 2):

Do you means the powershell command like below:

```
$MyVar = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Table
$MyVar | Get-Member -Type Properties
```

For more information you could visit https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281939(v=sql.105).aspx

If you want to get the value of table,

```
//Connect to the local, default instance of SQL Server. 
{ 
Server srv = default(Server); 
srv = new Server(); 
//Call the EnumCollations method and return collation information to DataTable variable. 
DataTable d = default(DataTable); 
//Select the returned data into an array of DataRow. 
d = srv.EnumCollations; 
//Iterate through the rows and display collation details for the instance of SQL Server. 
DataRow r = default(DataRow); 
DataColumn c = default(DataColumn); 
foreach ( r in d.Rows) { 
  Console.WriteLine("====================================="); 
  foreach ( c in r.Table.Columns) { 
    Console.WriteLine(c.ColumnName + " = " + r(c).ToString); 
  } 
} 
}
```

The above is how to do the job via C# but how to do that in powershell: You have got $MyVar values, and you run "$MyVar |Get-Member" is to show all method of all method available for $MyVar, I believe there should have some method allow you iterator all row or column for thr table. The powerShell even can invoke C# method, but this is the last choose.

Comment: Here i got only the properties of the table, not the values

Comment: @ultimatejegan see my Answer and If you can't find the method, then print the result to me.

Answer (score 2):

There is now an sqlserver module [available](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4627/new-powershell-cmdlets-to-read-and-write-sql-server-tables/) for `powershell`

You now have available the following two additional commands and options

```
Read-SqlTableData [[-ServerInstance] <String[]> ] [-ColumnName <String[]> ] [-ColumnOrder <String[]> ] [-ColumnOrderType <OrderType[]> ] [-ConnectionTimeout <Int32> ] [-Credential <PSCredential> ] [-DatabaseName <String> ] [-IgnoreProviderContext] [-OutputAs <OutputTypeSingleTable> {DataSet | DataTable | DataRows} ] [-SchemaName <String> ] [-SuppressProviderContextWarning] [-TableName <String> ] [-TopN <Int64> ] [ <CommonParameters>]

Write-SqlTableData [[-ServerInstance] <String[]> ] -InputData <PSObject> [-ConnectionTimeout <Int32> ] [-Credential <PSCredential> ] [-DatabaseName <String> ] [-Force] [-IgnoreProviderContext] [-Passthru] [-SchemaName <String> ] [-SuppressProviderContextWarning] [-TableName <String> ] [-Timeout <Int32> ] [ <CommonParameters>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AdoLib module in SQLPSX (SQLPSX.codeplex.com).

With that, you can use cmdlets and do things like:

```
invoke-sqlquery -sql "select * from tab" -server SQLServer01 -database MyDatabase
```