# Adding data from SQL server on Prem to SharePoint List using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am getting an error when running the PowerShell script. Error is related to a missing assembly. Script will get the data from the SQL server and query through each item in the SharePoint list and update the values if any changes.

I tried adding libraries in the PowerShell code but I am getting the same error.

```
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client\v4.0_16.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c...
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime\v4.0_16.0.0.0__71e9bce1...
Enter password: ************
5
Data Import Starts...
```

> New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery]: verify
>   that the assembly containing this type is loaded. At C:\SQL
>   Server\SQLSharepointLoad.ps1:55 char:16
>   +     $SPQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
>   +                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
>
> The property 'Query' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
>   property exists and can be set. At C:\SQL
>   Server\SQLSharepointLoad.ps1:56 char:5
>   +     $SPQuery.Query = "

Comment: Verify that you have SharePoint installed and can load the library `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery`

Comment: I am trying to move data from SQL server to SharePoint Online..

Comment: The SQL server will not have the SharePoint libraries installed. You will have to run the code from a SharePoint server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from SQL Server, you could use SQL Server PowerShell, check below thread.

[Using Powershell get Values from sql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543430/using-powershell-get-values-from-sql-table)

If you want to get data from SharePoint, I do suggest you use CSOM to query SharePoint list data(SPQuery is SSOM which can be run in SharePoint server).

You could get CSOM SDK from

2013

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585

2016

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51679

Sample PowerShell to connect SharePoint by PowerShell with CSOM.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e7894793-4d6f-4184-af2e-2ba685d6c90a/csom-powershell-and-sharepoint-2010-to-read-all-sites-subsites-libs-and-lists?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious